# JPA - use class as an entity and embeddable at once?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm JPA newbie and I have probably stupid question ;)

Let `Node` be a class representing some blog post.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="nodes")
public class Node {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    private String title;
    private String body;
}
```

I want to make an archive of deleted nodes in separate table (I don't want to mess `nodes` table with removed nodes using `deleted` flag). Archive entry should have additional fields: `DateTime deletedAt`, `String deletedBy` and maybe something else.

Is there any possibility to make a class `ArchivedNode` in the following way:

```java
@Table(name="archived_nodes")
@Entity
public class ArchivedNode {
    private DateTime deletedAt;
    private String deletedBy;
    // ...
    @Embedded
    private Node node;
}
```

? Or maybe there is a better solution for archiving entities in separate tables?

Comment: You cant directly since if something is an Entity then it has an "id" and an embedded object doesn't. You could have a Node, with an Embeddable that provides all fields of the Node for example, and then have that Embeddable object also stored in ArchivedNode.

Comment: Eclipselink has support for soft deletes and history tables https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/SoftDelete https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/History  Other providers should have something similar

Answer (score 0):

Create a JPA repository for `ArchivedNode`. Each time you wish to call the `delete()` method on a `Node`, convert the `Node` you wish to delete into an `ArchivedNode` and save the `ArchivedNode` into the archived_nodes table.

Also, the `Node` within `ArchivedNode` should be a `@OneToOne` unidirectional relationship.

```
...
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="id")
private Node node;
...
```